# Moving window with complete boundary in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stride

I have been using rolling/moving windows lately and all implementations I have seen so far ignore values contained in the boundaries of the array if these values can not be placed in a complete window. For example, assume you have this array:

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10)
Out[1]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

Using view_as_windows from scikit-image, you can see there are several elements (last two columns and last two rows) that can't be placed inside another `4x4` window:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows
view_as_windows(np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10), (4,4),4)

Out[14]:
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [10, 11, 12, 13],
         [20, 21, 22, 23],
         [30, 31, 32, 33]],

        [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [14, 15, 16, 17],
         [24, 25, 26, 27],
         [34, 35, 36, 37]]],


       [[[40, 41, 42, 43],
         [50, 51, 52, 53],
         [60, 61, 62, 63],
         [70, 71, 72, 73]],

        [[44, 45, 46, 47],
         [54, 55, 56, 57],
         [64, 65, 66, 67],
         [74, 75, 76, 77]]]])
```

I think `sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d` behaves in the same way. As far as I understand, both use stride tricks to obtain memory views of the array. However, I'd like to be able to obtain partial windows even if they don't have the same size.

Comment: Can the windows overlap?

Comment: I would prefer to have both options: overlapping and non-overlapping windows. There are applications for both.

Comment: The ```sliding_window``` function found at [Efficient Overlapping Windows with Numpy](http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268) will provide overlapping or non-overlapping *windowed* view of an N-D array using ```numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided```.  I imagine it could be modified to also return any *leftovers* - either the actual data or indices describing it.

Comment: `stride_tricks` won't handle windows of different sizes (e.g. 4x4 main ones, 4x2, 2x4 and 2x2 boundary ones).  It would be easier to add some dummy boundary values around the image.  You can fill, wrap, or replicate, as you see fit.

Comment: That's what I thought. I think your idea of adding some extra boundaries to obtain full windows is a good one.